# Difference between `x in List` vs `x in Dict` and `x in Set` (where `x` is a polars dtype)

Tags: python, python-polars

This is mostly a question about python:
How is `x in [a, b, c]` evaluated differently than `x in {a, b, c}`.

The context I'm struggling with is like this:

```py
import polars as pl
s = pl.Series(["a", "b"], dtype=pl.Categorical)

s.dtype in [pl.Categorical, pl.Enum]  # True
s.dtype in {pl.Categorical, pl.Enum}  # False
s.dtype in {pl.Categorical: 1, pl.Enum: 2} # False
```

I want to understand python better.
I also wonder whether polars can do anything to make the second case work, since it currently seems like a footgun.

Comment: Without knowing polars I would say that looks like a broken hashCode/equals-implementation.

Comment: In order to pass the containment check in set object the element(`s.dtype`) must pass the equality(`==`) and hash test. For example try `s.dtype in {pl.Categorical(), pl.Enum}`

Comment: might want to make a bug-report about it.
I kind of don't want to do it because I don't even know what polars is.

Comment: `{a, b, c}` is a **set**, not a dict.

Comment: @khelwood I have submitted an edit to include both sets and dicts in the title and sample code because the interesting behaviour is observable with both.

Comment: @julaine https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9564#issuecomment-1607859334

Comment: I think a feature request for a datatype selector that includes both Categorical and Enum (e.g. like the existing `pl.NUMERIC_DTYPES`, etc) would make sense?

Comment: @jqurious thanks for the link. So they not only have hashcode inconsistent with equals, they also have a non-transitive equals and are fine with it. At that point they just shouldn't call their function `__eq__`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: polars dtypes do not follow the usual equals-contract in multiple ways, and this is considered by design: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9564 (thanks @jqurious), specifically, they violate transitivity and hashcode-consistency. In polars, a specific datatype is considered equal to a more general datatype even when different specific datatypes are not equal to each other. eg "`pl.List == pl.List(str)` => True
`pl.List(int) == pl.List(str)` => False".

---

Original answer, where I assumed hashcode-inconsistency is all that is happening here:

This is a broken equality-implementation. See this:

```py
import polars as pl
s = pl.Series(["a", "b"], dtype=pl.Categorical)

print(s.dtype is pl.Categorical) # False 
print(s.dtype == pl.Categorical) # True
print(hash(s.dtype) == hash(pl.Categorical) ) # False
```

`s.dtype` is a new object that is considered equal to `pl.Categorical`. However, the `__hash__`-function is not overridden correctly: Two objects that are considered equal must have the same hashcode (or ban usage of the hash-function). Algorithms may rely on this and produce weird results if this is not true for a class! If you override `__eq__` on a class, read this: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__

What is happening here is that `obj in list` iterates the list and tests equality of the elements with obj, while `obj in set` uses the hashcode of obj to locate the object in the set, and if no object with that hashcode exists in the set the conclusion is that it is not in the set.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to @julaine, that answer isn't complete. TLDR: Categoricals are special.

If you do your example with another datatype, for instance Utf8 then let's see what happens...

```
s = pl.Series(["a", "b"],dtype=pl.Utf8)


s.dtype in [pl.Categorical, pl.Enum, pl.Utf8] 
### True
s.dtype in {pl.Categorical, pl.Enum, pl.Utf8}
### True
```

So what's the difference? Categoricals are special because they contain a mapping of strings to ints so one isn't the same as the other. When you compare two (for instance with `.is_in`) categoricals, it just uses the int representation and if the int:string mapping isn't the same then that'll obviously be broken. When you try to do that it'll raise an error.

I've likely dropped some nuance but at a high level, categoricals are special and other dtypes behave "properly" in the example.

Comment: Even if categoricals are special, shouldn't `__eq__` and `__hash__` still be in agreement with each other?

Comment: This is a valuable answer for people actually dealing with this problem, so I upvoted. But this is still a bug even if it only occurs with categoricals. If “one isn’t the same as the other” than they should not be ‘==‘-equal.